# Deselect object in Fabric JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I have created a canvas having a background image and then I open a file selector to render a dynamic image on the canvas. But when I select an image from the file selector a blue selector is showing on canvas.
How to disable that blue selector. Following is a screenshot of canvas with blue selector

[image]

I have tried

```
1) canvas.discardActiveObject();  
2) canvas.renderAll();  
3) canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();  
4) canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `canvas.selection = false;` to mouse move function.

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
//turn off selection
canvas.selection = false;
});
```

Comment: You no need to set `canvas.selection = false;` on mouse move, this is used for multi-selection, and one time is enough.